# iOS Auto-sorts New Stock Apps?

Tags: software-update, ios

I just updated my iPhone to iOS 10.2 and went looking for the new TV app. I was surprised to not find it on any of my home screens! Instead, it had been placed in my "Apple" folder, where I keep most of the (semi-useless) stock apps. It was even alphabetized correctly, having been inserted between "Tips" and "Voice Memos"!

How long has this feature existed? Does anyone know the history of this happening? Is it something that Apple has advertised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **TV** app is not new, Apple just renamed the **Videos** app.

You probably had the Videos app in the same location and when it was updated it just appeared to be placed alphabetically. In reality, since 'T' is close 'V' you might have just thought it automatically sorted itself.

Comment: Oh dear. You're right. Never has there been a more appropriate time for today's new emoji, the facepalm. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Yes it exists. Launch the Settings app
Tap General
Scroll down and tap Reset
Then tap on the Reset Home Screen Layout.

You will get a prompt informing you that “This will reset your home screen layout to factory defaults,” tap Reset Home Screen.

That’s it, the app icons on the Home screen should now be sorted as follows:

Apple’s Stock apps (that come pre-installed with iOS) will be placed in their factory default locations.
The remaining apps will be sorted alphabetically.

Please note that if you’ve created folders then they will be removed, which is probably the biggest downside of using this method.

Comment: That's not exactly what I asked. What I noticed is that the new TV app was sorted into the folder *I manually created,* which shows a level of "intelligence" that was unexpected.

Comment: So you created a folder, put all the Stock apps, and the new TV appeared in there and was alphabetical?

Comment: Exactly. The folder was there before the update and afterwards TV was in there. (Note: it's not *all* the stock apps, but certainly the majority of the less-useful ones. Calculator, Compass, Health, Watch, and the like.)

Comment: Its possible that the Apple OS recognizes the apps in that folder as Stock apps, like when it automatically names a folder based on the apps in that folder. It then labeled that folder as "Stock apps" and proceeded to sort those apps in Alpha order.

Comment: Well, the folder name didn't change--it's still called "Apple", which is the name I gave it originally. Also, I had hand-alphabetized them before this. It just recognized that and inserted the new one in the correct place.

Comment: The actual, visible title didn't change, but the title it has deep in the memory of your phone. It recognizes patterns, and therefore inserted the app where it think it should be.